# Why doesn't Resource.Id have a definition for my Button?

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/play5evenlighter"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/munchTitle"
    android:src="@drawable/titlelighternodonut"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/donutButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/strawdonut2"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is where the error appears, in the MainActivity.cs

```
ImageButton donutButton1 = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.donutButton1);
```

The error says that Munch2.Resource.Id does not contain a definition for donutButton1...

In the xml above, you can see that I have set the `android:id="@+id/donutButton1"` but the error still persist.

I think the error may have to do with the fact that I made the imageButton from scratch in the xml file as opposed to dragging it out from the toolbox in the designer.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to build the project? Sometimes the Resource.Id won't get generated until you rebuild.

Comment: @MaxHampton Yes I have tried to build the project, but the error still persists

Comment: Go to your `resource.designer.cs` file and see if other items are being generated. You may want to try to do a hard re-build by deleting the `resource.designer.cs` file and rebuilding your project. You will then need to re-add the item to your project(as it may be not included in the project)

Comment: Do you have "strawdonut2" in your drawable folder?

Comment: Yes, I do @YuriS. Thank you for your help; I am still trying to solve this.

Comment: The only reason why designer will not have that declaration is if something wrong in xml file. I suggest start removing attributes from donutButton1 in xml and build every time. That's how you will identify problematic attribute.Start with "<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/donutButton1" />